# PLSQL - Triggers: Cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table

Tags: sql, plsql, triggers

What I'm suppose to do is use a trigger to update the quantity sold in the inventory table when an order is placed in the concessions_sold table(an insert is used). I admit that I suck at PLSQL so I'm not sure if I'm going about this the right way. The error I'm getting is:

```
SQL> insert into concessions_sold
  2  values(33, 104, '26-Apr-09', 50);
insert into concessions_sold
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table
```

My code:

```
create or replace trigger LabEx5_1 after insert on Concessions_sold
for each row
begin
if inserting then
update
( 
select i.quantity 
from inventory i, concessions_sold cs, concession c
where i.inventory_id = c.inventory_id and c.concession_id = cs.concession_id
)
set quantity = :new.quantity;
end if;
end LabEx5_1;
/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all if you use a "For Each Row" trigger then you MUST NOT operate on the whole table, just one row, so

```
select i.quantity 
from inventory i, concession c
where i.inventory_id = c.inventory_id and c.concession_id = cs.concession_id
```

should be changed to

```
select i.quantity 
from inventory i, concessions_sold cs, concession c
where i.inventory_id = c.inventory_id and c.concession_id = :new.concession_id
```

Second, the update should be something like:

```
update inventory
set quantity = :new.quantity
where inventory_id = ( 
  select inventory_id from concession c where concession_id = :new.concession_id 
) ;
```

So the trigger should look like this:

```
create or replace 
trigger LabEx5_1 after insert on Concessions_sold
for each row
begin
  if inserting then
    update inventory
      set quantity = :new.quantity
    where inventory_id = ( 
      select inventory_id from concession c 
      where concession_id = :new.concession_id 
    ) ;
  end if;
end LabEx5_1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to update a join view in your trigger, which has several constraints on when this can be done; see the [Oracle documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/views001.htm#insertedID5) for more details.

This UPDATE should do what you're trying to achieve:

```
UPDATE inventory i 
 SET i.quantity = :new.quantity 
 WHERE i.inventory_id = 
  (SELECT c.inventory_id 
    FROM concessions c 
     WHERE c.concession_id = :new.concession_id)
```

Comment: Are you sure? Judging from Oracle documentation about the error message at http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28278/e1500.htm#sthref1037 this error can only occur with join views.

Comment: CREATE TABLE CONCESSIONS_SOLD (
       SITE_ID              NUMBER NOT NULL,
       CONCESSION_ID        NUMBER NOT NULL,
       DATE_SOLD            DATE NOT NULL,
       QUANTITY             NUMBER NOT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY (SITE_ID, DATE_SOLD, CONCESSION_ID)
);

Comment: Okay, I'm an idiot. The error was correct (about join views), but I totally missed the fact that it was thrown from the trigger. I've fixed up my response.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

1. the "after insert" and "If (inserting)" are redundent.  Remove the "If (inserting)" it's unnecessary since your trigger is limited to AFTER INSERT.  Just adds more code to read.
2. It seems you are trying lower your inventory when something is sold.  I don't see that you actually do that.
3. This is embeded query doesn't have a key associated with it. (This is were your error message comes from).

```
select i.quantity 
from inventory i, concessions_sold cs, concession c
where i.inventory_id = c.inventory_id and c.concession_id = cs.concession_id
```

4. You don't have a where clause and your inline-select doesn't limit the rows coming back from the inventory table.  If you do get this to work, you are going to update every row in your Inventory table.

To make your actual update clause work.

```
  UPDATE (
    SELECT **i.inventory_id**, i.quantity   
    FROM Inventory i
      , Concessions_sold cs
      , Concessions c   
    WHERE i.inventory_id = c.inventory_id   
    AND c.concession_id = **:NEW.concession_id** 
  )
  SET quantity = :new.quantity
```

Now it works there are a few problems:
1. Linking table is unnecessary.
2. The inline SQL is making this UPDATE statement more difficult to read and hence more difficult to modify in the future.

I would be much more explicit:

```
UPDATE Inventory
SET quatity = quanaity - :new.quanity
WHERE inventory_id IN (
  SELECT inventory_id
  FROM Conessions c
  JOIN c.concession_id = :NEW.concession_id
  )
```

Obviously there's no checks to see that inventory quantity actually exists, something else you might want to take into consideration.

So your new trigger would look like this.

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER LabEx5_1 AFTER INSERT ON Concessions_sold
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE Inventory
  SET quatity = quanaity - :NEW.quanity
  WHERE inventory_id IN (
    SELECT inventory_id
    FROM Conessions c
    JOIN c.concession_id = :NEW.concession_id
    );
END LabEx5_1;
```